# How do I access the UI thread for my WCF subscriber?

Tags: winforms, wcf, user-interface

I am currently developing a WCF Publish Subscribe service. The subscriber is a winform app. As the subscriber needs to implement the callback method for the service, which in my case is the PostReceived() method, and the publisher has the PublishPost() method.

For the PostReceived() method for my winform, it is unable to access the UI thread of my winform. The subscribe method is done on my main method. How do I program my PostReceived() method in such a way that it is able to access the labels and such of my mainForm?

**EDIT**

what I have tried so far is calling the mainForm object from my program.cs but it crashes when i run all 3 , stating the error that it is unable to access the UI thread.

**EDIT 2**

I have tried using the following code but there is an error for it.

```
mainForm b;   
public void PostReceived(string postSampleData)
    {
        b.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            b.lblSearch.Text = "lakjslkaja";
        });
```

After running the code, there is an error of

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  The solution that comes to my mind is to use a BackgroundWorker thread, and kick the WCF call off in that call.

Comment: How do I go about using the backgroundworker thread? I have editted my post above.

Comment: Actually, parapura's answer is better.  I've dealt with this before, but couldn't find a code sample to post for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PostReceived method should be something like this

```
void PostReceived()
        {
            yourform.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    yourform.button.Text = "new label";
                    //More stuff here
                });
        }
```

This will guarantee that all the stuff after **BeginInvoke** is invoked in the UI thread.

Comment: the code is meant to be put in which file? as my current code is being placed at program.cs, there is an error of An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate)' , if that error is because of I didnt enter any code in it itself, after typing 'mainform.' there isnt any UI codes for me to enter.

Comment: I would put it in the same file your UI is in, in other words your Windows Form file, not the program.cs file.

Comment: No matter where you decide to put it `Application.OpenForms[0]` will give you the Form if you only have one Form in your application

Comment: If you don't have lot of forms and your main form is called MainForm, do a `MainForm b = Application.OpenForms[0]` within your PostReceived function

Comment: The error your are getting is because `mainForm b` is set to null

Comment: hmm. I do have quite a few forms. it first runs loginForm, after logging in it will proceed to the mainForm. putting that code leads me to another error of , Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'App.mainForm'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)